# codeigniter file upload sometimes work and sometimes not

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

i have some problem with codeigniter in file uploading. sometimes the file is uploaded to the specific path, sometimes not. sometimes all works fine but i don't find the specific files on the server until i put manually with ftp a file inside the folder and magically appear the files uploaded before .

here's my code:

CONTROLLER:

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath($this->config->item('applications_path'));
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
        $config['max_size'] = '5120'; // kilobytes
        $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);



        if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->upload->display_errors());
            redirect('');
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $pathPdf = $upload_data['file_name'];
          ...
```

I also noticed that i can't access directly to the files by the link.

how can i solve?

Comment: change your **$config['max_size']** and check again

Comment: i've tryed also putting 10MB of size limit but it continue works sketchy

Answer (score 0):

it wroks for me

```
 if (!empty($_FILES['file_name']['name'])) {
        // Specify configuration for File 

        $config['upload_path'] = 'image_folder/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000000';


        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('file_name')) {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            .
            .
            .
        }

    }
```